# XGBoost and sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I am trying to use xgboost to run -using python - on a classification problem, where I have the data in a **numpy matrix X** (rows = observations & columns = features) and the labels in a **numpy array y**. 
Because my data are sparse, I would like to make it run using a sparse version of X, but it seems I am missing something as an error occurs.

Here is what I do :

```
# Library import

import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# Converting to sparse data and running xgboost

X_csr = csr_matrix(X)
xgb1 = XGBClassifier()
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_csr, label = y )      #to work with the xgb format
xgtest = xgb.DMatrix(Xtest_csr)
xgb1.fit(xgtrain, y, eval_metric='auc')
dtrain_predictions = xgb1.predict(xgtest)
```

etc...

Now I get an error when trying to fit the classifier :

```
File ".../xgboost/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 432, in fit
self._features_count = X.shape[1]

AttributeError: 'DMatrix' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Now, I looked for a while on where it could come from, and believe it has to do with the sparse format I wish to use. But what it is, and how I could fix it, I have no clue.

I would welcome any help or comments ! 
Thank you very much

Comment: Does this work with `X`?  What does `xgb` say about using sparse matrix?  They often aren't drop in replacements.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the xgboost scikit-learn API (http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn), so you don't need to convert your data to a DMatrix to fit the XGBClassifier(). Just removing the line

```
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_csr, label = y )
```

should work:

```
type(X_csr) #scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
type(y) #numpy.ndarray
xgb1 = xgb.XGBClassifier()
xgb1.fit(X_csr, y)
```

which outputs:

```
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=1,
   gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
   min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100, nthread=-1,
   objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
   scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True, subsample=1)
```

Comment: that means we can train a model with a sparse array correct?

Answer (score 0):

`X_csr = csr_matrix(X)` has many of the same properties as `X`, including `.shape`.  But it is not a subclass, and not a drop in replacement.  The code needs to be 'sparse-aware'.  `sklearn` qualifies; in fact it adds a number of its own fast sparse utility functions.

But I don't know how well the `xgb` handles sparse matrices, nor how it plays with `sklearn`.

Assuming the problem is with `xgtrain`, you need to look at its type and properties.  How does it compare with the one made with `xgb.DMatrix(X, label = y )`?

If you want help from some one who isn't already an `xgboost` user, you'll have to provide a lot more information about the objects in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the XGBoost training wrapper as opposed to the XGBoost sklearn wrapper. You can create a classifier as follows:

```
params = {
    # I'm assuming you are doing binary classification
    'objective':'binary:logistic'
    # any other training params here
    # full parameter list here https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md
}
booster = xgb.train(params, xgtrain, metrics=['auc'])
```

This API also has a builtin cross validation `xgb.cv` that works much better with XGBoost.

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/index.html#python

Tons more examples here https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/guide-python

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- The problem occurs due to DMatrix..num_col() only returning the amount of non-zero columns in a sparse matrix.
- Convert this matrix to Compressed Sparse Column format using scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.tocsc.
- You can refer to http://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1238#issuecomment-243872543